# How to read and write to a command prompt process (cmd.exe) with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, perl

I've been looking around google and SO for many hours now as I feel this question must have been asked, but I cannot find the right answers.
Many of the most similar questions ask how to send A command or series of them, at start up of the process. The difference I'm looking for help with is being able to continually send and receive commands to the process once I've started it. Essentially nesting an actual command prompt inside a WPF window.

This is how I've been trying to run the process. But I can't figure out how tell the process to wait for a input response.

```
public void startProcess()
    {
        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\";
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe"; // 

            process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOutputDataHandler;
            process.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessErrorDataHandler;

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            using (sWriter = process.StandardInput)
            {
                if (sWriter.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    sWriter.WriteLine(@"cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\SomeFolder\ ");
                    sWriter.WriteLine(@"Run_Script.pl");
                }
            }

            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
       // this method won't work, but this is the general idea I'm trying to figure out to implement.
        if (sWriter.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sWriter.WriteLine(txtInput.Text);
        }
    }

    public void ProcessOutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        // log is a output textbox that is updated on a timer
        txtLog.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { log += outLine.Data; }), null); 

    }

    public void ProcessErrorDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        txtLog.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { log += outLine.Data; }), null); 

    }
```

I tagged perl on this just because I'm trying to run a perl script with this.

Comment: Why not just create a whole new process for each command?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's not possible to understand what exactly you're trying to do. I will say that for sure, you should not be disposing `StandardInput` (which you are). In addition, depending on where and how `startProcess()` is called, the `WaitForExit()` could be a problem.

Comment: @EricScherrer The reason I can't do that is because the script has menu options, which leads to more menu options. And you don't always know which options you'll have to press in advance. Say you go select option 1, it takes you to Option 1 menu, now you have to answer a question. But you didn't know the answer before getting to it so I couldn't make a predefined command for it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho How can I open StandardInput in a way that doesn't dispose of it or block while also keeping the process open? Process doesn't appear to have any event handler for input like it does for output and error. I appreciate your help.

Comment: There's no event for input, because _your_ process generates the input. There's nothing for you to consume, so no need for an event. And there's no need to _"open StandardInput in a way that doesn't dispose of it"_, because it's _already open_. All you have to do is use it. Just get rid of the whole `using (sWriter = process.StandardInput)` statement, and for that matter the `if (sWriter.BaseStream.CanWrite)` (stdin is always writable), and just call `process.StandardInput.WriteLine()` directly (i.e. you don't even need the `sWriter` variable, if you just keep the `process` reference instead).

Comment: Okay, that explanation helped me understand this better. I've been able to get the script to launch, and read it. However I can't get the output back until I send at least 2 line returns. The first input sent starts the script `process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Run_Script.pl");` That should then return me the output which has the start menu with several selections. However if I do send another input, I'll get a message saying my selection was invalid (as the script's first menu asks to enter a menu selection between 1 and 10). I'm not sure why it won't give me the output back first.